# SharePoint Online - wrong file upload limit in document collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, file-upload, limitations

I have a document collection in SharePoint online where uploads fail after 250MB. That of course is the limit for list attachments. But it's definitely a document collection.

The only thing special about the document collection are the access permissions which are a bit peculiar: Uploaders don't have access to the root of the collection but only dedicated folders.

I'm wondering:

- Could the permissions somehow interfere with file uploads to the effect that SharePoint falls back on the 250MB limit instead of 250GB?
- Are there any other settings that may interfere with large file uploads to document collections?

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions setup should not cause the 250MB limit. Normally, if a user has the right to add items, they can upload files.

A few things can affect uploading big files:

1. How your library is set up.
2. If you’re syncing your library to your computer.
3. If you’re trying to upload a file over 250MB, it’s better to break it into smaller chunks.

More info on permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions

More info on limits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits